# Child of constraint mess - Set inverse undo previous pose

Tags: animation, constraints

[image]

[image]

I've never used Child of Constraint before and must've messed it up here. I'm making a dance animation and have Child of Constraint set up between the dancers' hips.  Please help. I have no idea how to fix this.

I've attached the blend file if anyone wants to take a look.

[image]

Comment: You've got other problems that should probably be addressed before tackling the child of constraint. Both the Male and Female are parented to the Male Control, while neither is parented to the Female Control. In Object Mode, the Female control moves nothing, while the Male Control moves them both. You may have done this to make animating easier, as if he is leading. But it would be better to keep the female parented to the female control, and if you want the male to lead, use a child of constraint to keep her with him. Create a clean scene and share, and I'll respond re: child of constraints.

Comment: @R-800 I'm confused by your reply. In object mode, I can move the female control which moves the female rig while Male Control moves only male rig. I don't get the same results as you do. I didn't add any extra parenting between the rigs, only child of constraint on the female's hips (called 'Master') to the male's hips (also called 'Master'). All of their movements are done in pose mode, none done in object mode.

Comment: My apologies. I can no longer see the problem I did originally. When I load it up this time, everything seems to work as it should. I don't know why it didn't before. Let me give another look and get back.

Comment: I'm not seeing any issues at all now. It's not even clear to me what you are wanting to achieve that isn't now being achieved. Female Control Master (hips) is child of constrained to Male Control Master, as it should be, and the one follows the other during the twirl, as it should. Could you try and clearly explain exactly what you are wanting to happen that isn't happening? Which pose is getting broken by setting inverse and when?

Comment: If you need multiple inverses-- which isn't unheard of-- you need to use multiple child-of constraints.  You can animate the influence of these constraints to switch between them.